# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function (need hand)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting following error when running this sql script

`Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function`

my sql query:

```
select distinct a.IMPORTBTCHSTATID, b.IMPORTBATCHID,
       SUBSTRING(a.XMLREQBODY, charindex('<PersonNumber>',a.XMLREQBODY)+14, (charindex('</PersonNumber>',a.XMLREQBODY)-charindex('<PersonNumber>',a.XMLREQBODY)-14)) as PersonNum
from FAILEDXMLBODY a inner join
     IMPORTBTCHSTAT b
     on a.IMPORTBTCHSTATID=b.IMPORTBTCHSTATID
where b.IMPORTBATCHID in ('252','253','265')
```

Comment: I added the SQL Server tag based on the syntax.

Comment: What's the connotation of the word "Failed" here in the table name? If this is actual XML you're working with (as opposed to malformed), why are you not using *XML* tools for accessing data within, rather than using string manipulation?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `CHARINDEX()` returns 0 if the string is not found and this generates an error.  A simple solution is to return `NULL` if a value is not found:

```
   SUBSTRING(a.XMLREQBODY,
             NULLIF(charindex('<PersonNumber>', a.XMLREQBODY), 0) + 14, 
             NULLIF(charindex('</PersonNumber>', a.XMLREQBODY), 0) - NULLIF(charindex('<PersonNumber>', a.XMLREQBODY), 0) - 14)
            ) as PersonNum
```

Comment: If the string is not found, CHARINDEX() returns 0, not NULL.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin . . . I had `NULL` on my mind as the solution.  That statement really made no sense in the context of the answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Yep, I understood

Comment: still no luck. getting same errror

Comment: @mnasir . . . This expression cannot be the cause of that error.  The problem may be elsewhere in your query, or perhaps you are referencing a view that is causing the problem.